# How do I prove that a statistic is a pivot?

Tags: statistics

In this example I have a sample out of a distribution with density $P_{\theta}(x) = 2x^{\theta} e^{−\theta x^2} I_{x \ge 0}$.
I know that for all $i \ge 1$ we have $X_i^2 \sim Exp(\theta)$.
If $\theta = 1$, then $T_1 = 2\sum_{1 \le i \le n}X_i^2 \sim X_{2n}^2$.
And now I have to show that $T_{\theta} = 2\sum_{1 \le i \le n} \theta X_i^2$ is a pivot.
A pivot is a function of which the probability function does not depend on $\theta$.
But how do I show that $T_{\theta}$ does not depend on $\theta$?

Btw: I tried to plug it first in LaTeX, so that it's easier to read. But that doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! To learn about how to type equations properly here, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. Basically you want to wrap your LaTeX codes in `$` signs. E.g. typing `$y = x^2$` gives $y = x^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $x \ge 0$. As $X_i^2 \sim exp(\theta)$ it follow that
$$P(\theta X_1^2 \le x) = P(X_1^2 \le \frac{x}{\theta }) = P( exp(\theta) \le \frac{x}{\theta })=1 - e^{- \frac{x}{\theta } \theta} = 1 - e^{-x} =P( exp(1) \le x).$$
So, we get that $\theta X_1^2 \sim \exp(1)$. Thus $Y_1 = \theta X_1^2$ is pivot. Hence $2 \sum_i Y_i$ is pivot as sum of independent pivot statistics
.